# getBluetoothLeAdvertiser() returns null

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
```

This returns null. I have tried on an API 21 and on an API 23 device, but with the same result. I have no idea what I am missing?

The app builds and runs just fine, until of course the advertiser is used and the app crashes.

I appreciate any help provided! :)

Comment: this might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441785/does-bluetoothleadvertiser-work-on-a-nexus-5-with-android-5-0

Comment: It's possible that your device does not support Bluetooth LE peripheral mode. Here's [discussion about supported models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482611/chipsets-devices-supporting-android-5-ble-peripheral-mode) and at the moment [this page](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html) is probably the best source for such information.

Comment: Wow, ok- thanks. Is there another way to broadcast a bluetooth signal from an android device then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the developer docs, link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBluetoothLeAdvertiser()).
You'll see that the null object is returned in the following case:

> Returns a BluetoothLeAdvertiser object for Bluetooth LE Advertising operations. Will return null if Bluetooth is turned off or if Bluetooth LE Advertising is not supported on this device.

If you are unsure whether the device supports Bluetooth at all you should check if the `BluetoothAdapter` returned by the system is `null`

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support Bluetooth
}
```

Then they advice you to call `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` to see if it is supported first.

```
if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()){
    //Device does not support Bluetooth LE
}
```

If it supports BLE you must check to see if Bluetooth is enabled and if not, make the user aware and resolve it.

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

That should cover most of the times the adapter is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Check for `mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()` before you start the scanning