# btAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported() always false

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I need to emulate beacon. I use devices

- Android 6.0 (LG, Nexus 5)
- Android 9.0 (Honor 10)

In my app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.3'
```

In my activity:

```
public void onClickGenerateBeacon(View view) {
        Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .setId2("1")
                .setId3("2")
                .setManufacturer(0x0118)
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))
                .build();
        BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
        boolean isSupported = false;
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled())
            isSupported = btAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();

        if (isSupported) {
            BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
            BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
            beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
        }
    }
```

But **isSupported** is always `false`. And as result not execute:

```
new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
```

How I can fix this? Is it possible to emulate beacons by this lib or maybe has another approach?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to fix this with the Android operating system installed on these phones.  The operating system itself blocks transmitting BLE advertisements if isMultipleAdvertisementSupported returns false.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441785/does-bluetoothleadvertiser-work-on-a-nexus-5-with-android-5-0) for the explanation about the Nexus 5.

In theory you can root your Nexus 5 and install a different ROM image that does not block BLE advertising.  I know from my own experience that the Android L beta 1 build for the Nexus 5 did allow advertising.  That ROM image is no longer available from Google, but you may be able to find another installable ROM for the Nexus 5 that does not block this.

As for Huawei Honor devices, many do not support advertising but some others do.  Here's a slightly dated [table](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html) that shows the ones known to support advertising.

Comment: To do beacon transmission I must use device from this table? Is it possible to do this by Android emulator?

Comment: Yes, you must use a device in that table, although newer devices not mentioned in the table may also work.  Android emulators do not emulate Bluetooth, so you cannot use them as transmitters.